# Transferring a passphrase protected private SSH key to another machine

Tags: ssh, centos, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen, passphrase

I am trying to use the same SSH keys on a new machine. This was my original setup:

```
~/.ssh/mykey 

~/.ssh has 700 permission
~/.ssh/mykey has 600 permission
```

I used `ssh -i` to specify the key used to log into a server.

I copied the paths, contents, and permissions of mykey to my new laptop.

Unfortunately, the passphrase I used old machine is not working for my new laptop. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like it is better to just create a new SSH key.